# Storing documents with attributes in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, blob

In Adobe Acrobat, I can embedded pieces of information, such as tagging some OCRed text (January 1, 2021) as the "date" with the label being "1/1/2021".
If we are storing documents (PDFs, TIFF) in SQL Server (blob, not FILESTREAM), can I tag/label/embed data the same way?  Maybe the better question is, if I were to load in a PDF that has such tags already, can I access them somehow?

Edited to address @Panagiotis Kanavos excellent question.

Comment: Why would you store PDFs as blobs in a database? Store them in the filesystem, and put the location in the databse instead. You can add whatever attribute columns to the documents table.

Comment: @SchmitzIT that's what BLOBs are for. SQL Server can actually store BLOBs in a specific folder using FILESTREAM storage. Its full-text-search crawler can extract attributes from PDF and TIFF file formats

Comment: @KyleSouza the attributes are stored *inside* the file so SQL Server doesn't care about them. Is the real question whether you can *access* them perhaps?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I actually never used blobs. Granted, I haven't done proper DBA work in years, so my knowledge is outdated. Thanks for giving me some pointers on how to learn something new :)